# Numpy trouble vectorizing certain kind of aggregation

Tags: python, numpy

I am having difficulty in vectorizing the below operation:

```
# x.shape = (a,)
# y.shape = (a, b)
# x and y are ordered over a.
# Want to combine x, y into z.shape(num_unique_x, b)

# Below works and illustrates intent but is iterative
z = np.zeros((num_unique_x, b))

for i in range(a):
    z[x[i], y[i, :]] += 1
```

Comment: Any repeats in `x` or `y`?  Give us a small diagnostic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `num_unique_x`, and the size of `z` suggests that this is a case where `x` and `y` have repeats, and that some of the `z` will be larger than 1.  In which case we need to use `np.add.at`.  But to set that up I'd have review its documentation, and possibly test some alternatives.

But first a no-repeats case

```
In [522]: x=np.arange(6)
In [523]: y=np.arange(3)+x[:,None]
In [524]: y
Out[524]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

See why I ask for a diagnostic example.  I'm guessing as to possible values.   I have to make a `z` with more than 3 columns.

```
In [529]: z=np.zeros((6,8),dtype=int)
In [530]: for i in range(6):
     ...:     z[x[i],y[i,:]]+=1 
In [531]: z
Out[531]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

The vectorized equivalent

```
In [532]: z[x[:,None],y]
Out[532]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
In [533]: z[x[:,None],y] += 1
In [534]: z
Out[534]: 
array([[2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]])
```

The corresponding `add.at` expression is

```
In [538]: np.add.at(z,(x[:,None],y),1)
In [539]: z
Out[539]: 
array([[3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3]])
```

So that works for this no-repeats case.

For repeats in `x`:

```
In [542]: x1=np.array([0,1,1,2,3,5])
In [543]: z1=np.zeros((6,8),dtype=int)
In [544]: np.add.at(z1,(x1[:,None],y),1)
In [545]: z1
Out[545]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Without `add.at` we miss the `2s`.

```
In [546]: z2=np.zeros((6,8),dtype=int)
In [547]: z2[x1[:,None],y] += 1
In [548]: z2
Out[548]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, and yes your assumption of repeats within x is correct, and I failed at your last example where I was missing, as you said, the 2s. `ufunc.at` is a useful technique to have.